# SQL compare one column, then another, by using max over partition by

Tags: sql, hana

DB: SAP HANA

I have asked this question before, but now I'm facing more complicated question. When `qty` is the same, I want to return **biggest** `no`.

A

| user | no | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | **20** |
| A | 11 | **20** |
| B | 12 | 40 |
| B | 13 | 10 |

B

| id | user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

Expected result

| id | user | no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 11 |
| 2 | B | 12 |

I try

```sql
SELECT
    B.id,
    B.user,
    C.max_qty_no
FROM
    B
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        A.user,
        CASE
            WHEN A.qty = (
              MAX(A.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY A.user)
            ) THEN A.no
        END as max_qty_no
    FROM
        A
) C ON C.user = B.user AND
       C.max_qty_no IS NOT NULL;
```

return

| id | user | no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 1 | A | 11 |
| 2 | B | 12 |

Comment: Please note that due to HANA's columnar nature it may be **much** faster and less resource consuming to do `where (col, meas) in ( select f.col, max(f.meas) from same_table as f group by f.col)` because it is a pure columnar operation which is executed in OLAP engine. In contrast, analytic functions require row engine which involves early tuple reconstruction and defeats all the columnar benefits. In my local test with `tableA` structure, 10M rows and 1000 groups the difference is 2 times (in memory footprint and timings), though it is still a 0.3 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the `MAX(no)` per user having the largest quantity you need to apply additional selection criteria. The partitioning takes care of selecting the rows with `MAX(qty)` per user but you still need to select the rows with `MAX(no)` for each distinct user - you can do this by using the `MAX` aggregate function combined with a `GROUP BY`. With this small change you can return the expected results:

```sql
SELECT
    B.id,
    B.user,
    MAX(C.max_qty_no)
FROM
    B
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        A.user,
        CASE
            WHEN A.qty = (
              MAX(A.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY A.user)
            ) THEN A.no
        END as max_qty_no
    FROM
        A
) C ON C.user = B.user AND
       C.max_qty_no IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY B.id, B.user;
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to rank the A rows per user and only select the best-ranked row. So far this ranking was on one column only, so you could simply compare the value with the maximum value. Now, however, the ranking must be done considering two columns instead of just one. You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this ranking:

```
select id, user, no
from
(
  select
    b.id, b.user, a.no,
    row_number() over (partition by b.user order by a.qty desc, a.no desc) as rn
  from a
  join b on b.user = a.user
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```